# vega-lite: how to specify date in JSON as separate fields containing year, month, and day numbers?

Tags: d3.js, vega, vega-lite

My JSON data is a list of objects, each object contains the date in this format:

```js
  "date" : {
    "year" : 2019,
    "month" : 2,
    "day" : 17
  },
```

How can I tell Vega-lite that this is a date?
I have worked around this by creating another day field that is a string concatenating these three fields, and using:

```js
    "format" : {
      "parse" : {
        "day" : "date: '%Y %m %d'"
      }
```

But I'd like to be able to just use the existing 3 fields....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a calculate transform, along with the `datetime` expression. For example ([vega-editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSA3WAbArgKYDOKYA2uBhMDAoWbQJ6GwBOZATAAwCMAnABooAWwD2AO3gALLsLpMyvAKwBfeTlxL1VarTjwGqZqw6oeA+eKmzz8uItS8AbOqiauO6jTqHGkFnYuPiFRSRk5KAclAHY3bDwyABYvb316f0CzMAtQyGsIuyjYRzBeAA54j1QAZlS9XyM0ANNgyzCbSIUlfirE1DVBXQx0v2MWoPMQq3DbHPsS4L6tVFdhgF0qVMh4NlgJYgAzMTYRMko9YcwAYzxr-FwM1Eb4AEsRQgAKA3wRADoDIQ-llhD9-oC-gVpKCEL8AfR4UwAJSQIbeKCwUjPa5iEQAI1eEkI0Egw1UVHWaNE7AA1mRIOxWKiqJBCBIcdBCQBzRjDSAAD38h1ehFwJOxuIJRJJ8ngTAADk0doQRPKTol6lBSrRhaLxe5ErKFUqAI74fZvRBvLAMckQcmqIA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": {"year": 2019, "month": 2, "day": 15}, "val": 1},
      {"date": {"year": 2019, "month": 2, "day": 16}, "val": 2},
      {"date": {"year": 2019, "month": 2, "day": 17}, "val": 4},
      {"date": {"year": 2019, "month": 2, "day": 18}, "val": 3},
      {"date": {"year": 2019, "month": 2, "day": 19}, "val": 5},
      {"date": {"year": 2019, "month": 2, "day": 20}, "val": 6}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "datetime(datum.date.year, datum.date.month, datum.date.day)",
      "as": "combined"
    }
  ],
  "mark": "area",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "combined", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "val", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!  Why is month 2 considered to be March instead of February?  Is there a way to subtract one from the month in the calculate expression you wrote above?  Revised: changing to datum.date.month - 1 works!

Comment: Further revision: month being zero-based is indeed documented behavior of date time()

Comment: Yes, month is zero-based according to the docs: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#datetime. You can change it to ``date.month - 1`` within the calculate expression if you want to use normal 1-based months.